# norm of projection

Tags: functional-analysis

How to find the norm of the following projection:( sup-norm)

$c$ is the space of *convergent* sequences. $P:c\to c_0$ by $P(x_0,x_1,x_2,\ldots)=(x_0-\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n,x_1-\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n,x_2-\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n,\ldots)$.

Comment: First question : You are on an infinite-dimensional space, so there is no canonical choice of norm now. What norm are you using? Then you can have a hope of computing it!

Comment: I am using sup-norm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming the sup-norm on the sequence space, the norm of this projection is $2$. Indeed, the limit of $x_n$ does not exceed the norm of the sequence, so the norm of the difference is not larger than twice the norm of the original sequence. The sequence $(-1,1,1,1,\dots)$ is an example on which the quorum is doubled by the projection.

Comment: Can you detail... I mean, the question was not "What" is the norm, but rather "How to find it".

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva you are terribly wrong about the norm of projections, my friend. Your claim is only true for orthogonal projections in Hilbert spaces.

Comment: Okay, second mistake from me today :D But still, it would be nice to see some details. (I removed my wrong part in my comment.)

Comment: I know this norm 2. But I can't do it.

Comment: @Vladimir : Yes, that's better. =D Can you do it now nuarslandogan?

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva There's not much left to do...

Comment: @Vladimir : Funny, I actually never took the time to compute the norm of a non-orthogonal projection. A weird reflex.

Comment: @DavidMitra : Of course, but he did this comment after the edit, so..

Comment: Thanks Vladimir and Patrick

Comment: @Vladimir thanks

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva  thaks

Comment: Thanks to all. Never mind.